# Select rows that do not have other records for a specific field

Tags: mysql

Ciao everybody, I have the following table:

ID - COL_A - COL_B

I need to retrieve all the records that have COL_A = 1 and COL_B that has COL_A = 1 must not have other records with COL_A = 2.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for `NOT EXISTS` I think:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE COL_A = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable
                  WHERE t1.COL_B = t2.COL_B AND COL_A = 2)
```

You can also use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.COL_B = t2.COL_B AND t2.COL_A = 2
WHERE t1.COL_A = 1 AND t2.COL_A IS NULL
```